# ASP.NET WebForms - Session Variables Null

Tags: asp.net, session, webforms

I have an iframe keep alive (iframe that hits a page, defibrillator.aspx, on my site every few minutes to keep the session alive) on my masterpage for an asp.net app.  This works most of the time but every so often my session variables return null during the page load on my defibrillator page.  At first, I thought the session was being timed out by the server for some reason so I put some logging into the Session_End event in the global.asax but it was never hit.

Any ideas what could cause the session to be lost.

Comment: What is your session state mode?  InProc?

Answer (score 2):

Many things can cause session to be lost.  An AppPool recycle, iisreset, the client could lose its session cookie, etc.  Without knowing more it is difficult to tell what is the problem.

If session is so critical that you poll the application to keep the worker process from sleeping perhaps you ought to look into [persisting your session state to SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311209).

Answer (score 2):

[Peter Bromberg outlines the primary reasons for ASP.NET session timeouts](http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2007/10/losing-aspnet-sessions-why-application.html) on his blog.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same sort of problem, storing a shopping cart state in Session but having it randomly return null instead. I think I found the answer on Bertrand Le Roy's blog, which seems to work for me:

> Session loss problems can also result
>   from a misconfigured application pool.
>   For example, if the application pool
>   your site is running is configured as
>   a web farm or a web garden (by setting
>   the maximum number of worker processes
>   to more than one), and if you're not
>   using the session service or SQL
>   sessions, incoming requests will
>   unpredictably go to one of the worker
>   processes, and if it's not the one the
>   session was created on, it's lost. The
>   solutions to this problem is either
>   not to use a web garden if you don't
>   need the performance boost, or use one
>   of the out of process session
>   providers.

[Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2004/08/03/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the chosen persistence mechanism is InProc then it can be triggered by many things. Totally counter-recommended for a production environment.